# The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized When accessing SSRS through Proxy WinForms

Tags: sql, winforms, reporting-services, proxy

When i am accessing SSRS SQL 2008R2 through a Proxy Server in a WinForm an getting the following error 
'The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.'

This is my Request URL : [http://10.0.0.48/ReportServer_SQL_2008R2/Reportservice2005.asmx] 
Port : 80

Proxy Address : [http://192.168.4.1:7777/]

When checking through Fidler, it did not pass any values.

Answer (score 0):

Just check out with the user information. The user id and password you have used has the access to the report server?

If not grant them permission through report server security. and It will work.